# Why doesn't min-content work with auto-fill or auto-fit?

Tags: css, css-grid, fluid-layout, css-multicolumn-layout

Basically, I do not understand why this works:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, min-content);
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, min-content);
}
```

I really wish to make the latter functionality possible. Are there other ways to make it work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The second rule doesn't work because `min-content` is an *intrinsic sizing function*.

> [§ 7.2.2.1. Syntax of
>   `repeat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-syntax)
>
> - Automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) cannot be combined
>     with **intrinsic** or **flexible** sizes.
>
> [§ 11. Grid
>   Sizing](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#layout-algorithm)
>
> - An intrinsic sizing function (`min-content`, `max-content`, `auto`,
>     `fit-content()`).
> - A flexible sizing function [[is a dimension with the `fr` unit](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)].

Comment: Also I want to know WHY

Comment: @DavidGenger, when you reach the spec level, you're at the source. The "why" can only be answered by the spec writers and browser implementers. Could be due to technical complexity, conflict with other functions, or just a choice that needed to be made at a fork in the road. Who knows? But hopefully the issue is addressed in Grid Level 2.

Comment: What doesn't make sense is why it matters to `repeat` whether its an intrinsic size or not.  At the end of the day, a size is still calculated, so why can't the browser just use the calculated size that comes as a result of the intrinsic sizing function?

Answer (score 2):

I've worked around this by doing

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(0, max-content));`

This ensures that the grid tracks are created with a minimum size that is not "intrinsic" whilst allowing the tracks to expand to fit based on the `max-content`.  I use `auto-fit` instead of `auto-fill` sometimes depending on use case, but both should work.

Comment: that won't wrap to multiple rows instead it squishes the elements

Comment: replacing `0` with some minimum value works best in my case. Here is my code: `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(256px, max-content))`