Grid-auto-rows with auto - how controlling the height of the last line?
I need to create a grid container with an unknown number of rows - so that all but the last row occupy the height of the content, and the last row (regardless of the height of the content) occupies the remaining height of the grid container.
Here is my HTML variation:
 <div className="grid-container">
      <div className="item">some data 1 </div>
      <div className="item">some data 2</div>
      <div className="item">some data 3</div>
      <div className="item">some data 4</div>
      <div className="last-item">last one</div>
    </div>

I've been trying to do:
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, min-content) 1fr;
  height: 500px; /* It doesn't really matter, it's just for clarity's sake. */
}
.item {
 height: max-content;
}


 grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, min-content) 1fr; - its not valid code (just my attempt to solve the problem), but I don't know how to solve this problem, help please and thanks advance


ok, the height percentage is my mistake - I apologize, I'll fix it now for clarity.

Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504049/why-doesnt-min-content-work-with-auto-fill-or-auto-fit

Is grid really necessary as this would be easy to implement using flexbox?

Sorry but this is not a duplicate, my question is not why it doesn't work why min-content doesn't work with auto-fill or the like - I read this question before posting.
my question is how to create a grid with an unknown number of rows - provided that all but the last row occupy the height of the content content, and the last row stretches to the full available height of the grid container.

@Adam, i know - the problem is that the items come from the server and they contain certain grid-areas

So essentially, you cannot do this with CSS-Grid. Flexbox is require here I suspect.

not too sure what you expect from min-content as height sizing ? , with grid, you need to set a known numbers of rows. With the selectors :has(:nth-child(X) , if you use a preprocessor, you may easily generate so many selectors/grid-template-rows to match so many possibilities. Example of the idea that works untill you reach 10 children https://jsfiddle.net/egjaw35m/ because 10 selectors are already written to match those. flex makes it easier, draw it as a column then set flex-grow:1 to :last-child. If you do not draw columns but only rows, then grid is useless, it's here a flex job

After trying all the combinations possible with CSS grid, I come to the conclusion that this cannot be achieved with CSS grid.
We can only achieve this with flexbox and that's why perhaps we say Grids works perfectly in sync with flexbox.


.grid-container {
      display: flex; 
      flex-direction: column; 
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .grid-item {
      flex: 0 1 auto; 
    }

    .last-item {
      flex: 1 1 auto; 
      background: orange;
    }
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="grid-item">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis illo quibusdam voluptas
        veritatis? Qui unde totam quas dicta, omnis officiis.
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, impedit.
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, dolore.
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, ipsa.
      </div>
      <div class="last-item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus ipsam inventore labore
        mollitia nesciunt rerum maxime rem officia quam ex?
      </div>
      </div>




Unfortunately, I am also convinced of this.
The problem is that this implementation on our project is not possible through flex

You can use JavaScript in that case, If you are allowed to do so.
With JS we can add class as per our requirement.
Then even CSS grid can be wisely used. And even flexbox
